# How to create a centered rounded shadow smaller than element width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make shadow like this below but I don't know how to make shadow like this in css. Can any one help me to make this style?

[image: Shadow to Create]

Comment: Shadow like what?

Comment: Please provide more information. Also, you forgot to upload the picture showing what kind of shadow you are talking about.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o23z6.jpg like this

Comment: There is box-shadow or text-shadow and depending on what you need to put a shadow on I'm not sure which one you need to use.,

Comment: i want to use box-shadow look this picture plz  i.stack.imgur.com/o23z6.jpg

Comment: Something like this should be close: box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px -5px #333;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with negative box spread shadow distance like this:

```css
.item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"> </div>
```

Or take a look at those examples: https://paulund.co.uk/learn-css-box-shadow.